# How to use pandas and numpy to compare two excel workbooks with multiple tabs?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, compare

I have two xlsx files that have multiple tabs. I need to compare values in each tab based on the tab name. (e.g. sheet1 in file1 needs to be compared with sheet1 in file2 and so on). When I use the following code, it will only compare and write the first sheet. Please help me figure out why all tabs do not get compared.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_excel('test_1.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
df2 = pd.read_excel('test_2.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

with pd.ExcelWriter('./Excel_diff.xlsx') as writer:
    for sheet, df1 in df1.items():
        # check if sheet is in the other Excel file
        if sheet in df2:
            df2 = df2[sheet]
            comparison_values = df1.values == df2.values

            print(comparison_values)

            rows, cols = np.where(comparison_values == False)
            for item in zip(rows, cols):
                df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = '{} → {}'.format(df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]], df2.iloc[item[0], item[1]])

            df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=False, header=True)
```

The test_1 file is set up as follows.

Sheet1

```
|test 1|test 2|test 3|
|------|------|------|
|1     |1     |1     |
|1     |1     |1     |
|1     |1     |1     |
```

Sheet2

```
|test 1|test 2|test 3|
|------|------|------|
|3     |3     |3     |
|3     |3     |3     |
|3     |3     |3     |
```

The test_2 file is set up as follows.

Sheet1

```
|test 1|test 2|test 3|
|------|------|------|
|2     |2     |2     |
|2     |2     |2     |
|2     |2     |2     |
```

Sheet2

```
|test 1|test 2|test 3|
|------|------|------|
|4     |4     |4     |
|4     |4     |4     |
|4     |4     |4     |
```

Here is the output I get using the code above.

Sheet1

```
|test 1|test 2|test 3|
|------|------|------|
|1 → 2 |1 → 2 |1 → 2 |
|1 → 2 |1 → 2 |1 → 2 |
|1 → 2 |1 → 2 |1 → 2 |
```

Here is the output I get if I align the df1.to_excel function with the 'if' statement.

Sheet1

```
|test 1|test 2|test 3|
|------|------|------|
|1 → 2 |1 → 2 |1 → 2 |
|1 → 2 |1 → 2 |1 → 2 |
|1 → 2 |1 → 2 |1 → 2 |
```

Sheet2

```
|test 1|test 2|test 3|
|------|------|------|
|3     |3     |3     |
|3     |3     |3     |
|3     |3     |3     |
```

**Here is the output I want that shows the difference in values by sheet name.**

Sheet1

```
|test 1|test 2|test 3|
|------|------|------|
|1 → 2 |1 → 2 |1 → 2 |
|1 → 2 |1 → 2 |1 → 2 |
|1 → 2 |1 → 2 |1 → 2 |
```

Sheet2

```
|test 1|test 2|test 3|
|------|------|------|
|3 → 4 |3 → 4 |3 → 4 |
|3 → 4 |3 → 4 |3 → 4 |
|3 → 4 |3 → 4 |3 → 4 |
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a colleague I was able to troubleshoot the problem with my excel sheet comparison code. Within the 'if' loop, df2 was being overwritten. I changed the name from df2 to df2sheet within the 'if' loop and now it works beautifully.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_excel('test_1.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
df2 = pd.read_excel('test_2.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

with pd.ExcelWriter('./Excel_diff.xlsx') as writer:
    for sheet, df1 in df1.items():
        # check if sheet is in the other Excel file
        if sheet in df2:
            df2sheet = df2[sheet]
            comparison_values = df1.values == df2sheet.values

            print(comparison_values)

            rows, cols = np.where(comparison_values == False)
            for item in zip(rows, cols):
                df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = '{} → {}'.format(df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]], df2sheet.iloc[item[0], item[1]])

            df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=False, header=True)
```